# Does sending the same message with 2 different keys in OTP leak information?

Tags: one-time-pad, xor

Suppose a common message ($M$) is XOR'ed with two different keys $K_1,K_2$ producing two ciphertexts $C_1,C_2$. Thus,

$$M \oplus K_1 = C_1\\
M \oplus K_2 = C_2$$

On observing $C_1$ and $C_2$, an adversary can obtain the value of $C_1 \oplus C_2 = K_1 \oplus K_2$. Is this scheme semantically secure? Note that $|K_1|=|K_2|=|M|$ and the keys are randomly chosen from a uniformly distributed large key space ($\approx 2^{255}$).

Comment: In the OTP, what is the aim ? Hide the key or hide the message ? Also remember that the key are uniformly distributed.

Comment: Is $|M| = 255 bits$?

Comment: @Biv The aim is to determine whether $C1$ and $C2$ gives any extra information about $M$. Thus is-
$E(M|C1,C2)=E(M)$\\
$K_1$ and $K_2$ are two different keys which have same length of that of $M$ and are chosen randomly from a uniformly distributed key space.

Comment: @HenrickHellström: yes $|M| = 255 bits$

Comment: @DebanjanSadhya then I would advise you to, simplify your scheme: consider that $M$ is only 1 bit long, idem for $C$ and $K$. What is the probability that $K_1 = 1$, that $K_1 = 0$ idem for $K_2$. Then add $M$ in the mix. What pieces of information did you gain ? What pieces of information do you want to gain ? Try a case study.

Comment: @Biv: Since the simplified scheme has 1 bit long $(M,K_1,K_2)$, then $Pr(M)=Pr(K_1=1)=Pr(K_1=0)=Pr(K_2=1)=Pr(K_2=0)=0.5$. Since the $Enc$ is essentially a One Time Pad, $Pr(M|C_1)=Pr(M|C_2)=Pr(M)$ (since we are XOR'ing $K_1$ and $K_2$ to $M$). However I'm not able to figure out whether $Pr(M|C_1,C_2)=Pr(M)$ ?

Comment: Be careful you are mixing notations !!! $Pr(M)$ means nothing.

Comment: @Biv: apologies for any confusion, $Pr(M)$ denotes the probability associated with the plaintext (which is known to the adversary). For a 1bit message space $Pr(M)=0.5$.

Comment: @DebanjanSadhya Then do a case study : fix things, see how it evolves. If $C_1 = 0$ and $C_2 = 0$ : what is the probability of $M = 1$, what is the probability of $M = 0$. If $C_1 = 0$ and $C_2 = 1$, what is the probability of $M = 1$, what is the probability of $M = 0$ and so on... Yes this is long, but it should help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the keys $K_i$ are only used once, this is semantically secure.  To see it, observe that if $K_i$ is a uniformly random value in $\{0,1\}^{|M|}$ then so is $C_i = M \oplus K_i$.